# How to use array type column value in CASE statement

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with two columns, `listA` stored as `Seq[String]` and `valB` stored as `String`. I want to create a third column `valC`, which will be of Int type and its value is
`iff valB is present in listA then 1 otherwise 0`

I tried doing the following:

```scala
val dfWithAdditionalColumn = df.withColumn("valC", when($"listA".contains($"valB"), 1).otherwise(0))
```

But Spark failed to execute this and gave the following error:

```scala
cannot resolve 'contains('listA', 'valB')' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, 'listA' is of array type.;
```

How do I use a array type column value in CASE statement?

Thanks,
Devj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple udf that will check if the element is present in the array :

```
val arrayContains = udf( (col1: Int, col2: Seq[Int]) => if(col2.contains(col1) ) 1 else 0 )
```

And then just call it and pass the necessary columns in the correct order :

```
df.withColumn("hasAInB", arrayContains($"a", $"b" ) ).show

+---+---------+-------+
|  a|        b|hasAInB|
+---+---------+-------+
|  1|   [1, 2]|      1|
|  2|[2, 3, 4]|      1|
|  3|   [1, 4]|      0|
+---+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `array_contains`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{expr, array_contains}

df.withColumn("valC", when(expr("array_contains(listA, valB)"), 1).otherwise(0))
```