# How to use in column operator with value and list from columns?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Please note that I'm not asking how to do what `array_contains` could, but I'm curious whether there is any way to use `in` or `isin` to do the same. I think there is a way, but it seems too late to think clearly.

---

Is there any way to use `in` SQL predicate or `isin` column operator with the list to match that comes with values from a column?

Say I've got the following `nums` dataset:

```
scala> nums.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- nums: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)

scala> nums.show
+---+---------+
| id|     nums|
+---+---------+
|  1|[1, 2, 3]|
+---+---------+
```

I'd like to write a query to use `in` / `isin` predicate using `id` and `nums` columns.

`nums.where($"id" isin $"nums")` does not seem to work due to type mismatch:

```
scala> nums.where($"id" isin $"nums").show
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(`id` IN (`nums`))' due to data type mismatch: Arguments must be same type but were: int != array<int>;;
'Filter id#18 IN (nums#19)
+- AnalysisBarrier
      +- Project [_1#15 AS id#18, _2#16 AS nums#19]
         +- LocalRelation [_1#15, _2#16]
```

Comment: Does the `filter` predicate fit your needs? https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/24/working-with-nested-data-using-higher-order-functions-in-sql-on-databricks.html

Comment: Are they available in the latest Spark SQL 2.3? If not, they don't fit my needs.

Comment: And similar in Scala [How to use array type column value in CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46220883/8371915)

Comment: Please re-consider when you vote to close the question when suggesting to use `array_contains`. I'm interested in what features `in` / `isin` miss to match `array_contains` if any.

Comment: If you want to reopen this I want oppose (you can do it single handed anyway, right?), but I don't think there is really a question here, so I won't do it myself. You already analyzed the API and concluded that it is not supported. Personally I don't recall any system that supports `IN collection` (Oracle has `x member of array`, PostgreSQL has `x = ANY(array)`), so it is possible it is a matter of compliance with standard, or just _we do it like this because everyone does_.

Comment: As per documentation `expression that is evaluated to true if the value of this expression is contained by the **evaluated** values of the arguments.` In the source code you can clearly see that isin is varargs method, and parameter converted either to List or Set. Therefore you can't do it without collecting.

Comment: Thanks @user6910411 @addmeaning for your help. I finally "discovered" that even `nums.filter("id in (select nums from numsT)").show` won't do any good and I stand corrected. Sorry for the noise.