# How to use Spark SQL SPLIT function to pass input to Spark SQL IN parameter

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data set similar to the one shown below :

```
color   :   fruit  
--------------------
red     :    mango
yellow  :    banana
```

This above df is registered to TEMP table.

There is a input string like this: `'red,yellow'`

```
select * from TEMP tmp where tmp.color IN(SPLIT('red,yellow',','))
```

Tried with explode and `concat_ws` but not worked.

Need to do changes at Spark SQL level, so how to pass comma separated data to IN parameter in Spark SQL,

Comment: Related [How to use in column operator with value and list from columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50123643/9613318)

Comment: ARRAY_CONTAINS we can use here with SPLIT combination